# CSS for div Scrolling inconsistent

Tags: html, css, sass, jekyll

I'm attempting to create a "bookshelf" using html and sass (Note:  this is heavily based on http://ameijer.nl/2013/03/bookshelf-css-only/)  You can see my version of the concept here:

https://mainstringargs.github.io/bookshelf.html

I'm trying to only show the horizontal scrollbar when necessary for the particular "bookshelf" -- for example, in the "Read" shelf above -- but not have it appear when not necessary -- see "Reading" & "On Deck" at the link.

I expected using "overflow: auto;" would give me this effect, but that seems to cause the scrollbar to always appear.

The relevant sass file is here:  https://github.com/mainstringargs/mainstringargs.github.io/blob/master/src/styles/_bookshelf.scss

How can I only show the horizontal scrollbar when needed for each particular bookshelf?

As an example, it currently looks like this with horizontal scrollbars on both displayed bookshelfs even when not enough books:

[image]

I want it to look like this mockup (Note the bottom bookshelf has no horizontal scrollbar because there aren't enough books there, but the top one does because there are enough books to scroll):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox and let `.books` overflow vs `.shelf` just be sure to remove the `width: 1470px;` from `.books, .shelf:after`:

```
.shelf {
    height:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}
.books {
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
    align-items:flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    height: 420px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.books, .shelf:after {
    /* width: 1470px; */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 40px 30px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.book {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work only if you remove overflow: auto from .books

Comment: Thanks for the help -- this isn't quite what I had in mind, but it does seem to do the trick by scrunching the books closer together.  I was actually hoping to keep the layout the same, but only show the horizontal scrollbar when necessary.  Please see my latest edit for a clarification and mockup screenshot

Comment: I made some edits for consistency. Make sure that  `flex-shrink: 0;` is getting set on `.book`. Without that, they will all "scrunch" to fit within the shelf and they won't overflow. Also, try pasting my code above into inspector-stylesheet. It should be a pixel-perfect match, at least it was for me when comparing two tabs (one tab with edits, one without).

Comment: Thanks again -- I think I'm close to get it working, but for some reason I just can't get it.  (Note I'm a novice when it comes to this css stuff).  I sort of have it, but now the "bookshelf" background isn't appearing.  In the ```.shelf:after``` if I have the ```content``` commented out, the scrollbars work as I want, but then the background does not appear.  If I have the ```content``` included, the bookshelf appears as I want, but then the scrollbars do not work as I want.

Comment: Looks like a z-index issue. So uncomment `content` to get the background to show and add `.books { z-index: 1; }`

Comment: You're the best!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your code if you only want to apply a horizontal scroll when necessary and not vertically.

Use the following on your class name:

```
.books {
    overflow-x: auto; // Auto horizontal
    overflow-y: hidden; // Disable vertical scrolling
}
```

Try that see if it works. No need to add scroll but let the browser decide with the "auto" set.

Comment: Thanks for the help -- your answer works for the whole browser, but I was intending the scrollbar to hide/show specific to each 'bookshelf'.  Please see my edit for clearer language and screenshots